# Is it possible to await a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The keyword `await` makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result.

I noticed its possible to `await` a function

```
var neonlight = await neon();
```

Is it possible to `await` a class?

**Example**

```
var neonlight = await new Neon(neon_gas);
```

Comment: `await` is for asynchronous functions, and as far as I know constructors can't be asynchronous. Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: what is a point of doing that ?

Comment: I don't like that this was closed as a duplicate in favor of a bunch of dated (and wrong) answers stating **"this isn't possible"**, when clearly given Taki's answer below, it *is* possible.  I am voting to reopen this question, in favor of marking *those* as duplicates of *this* question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically .. Yes, If the constructor returns a `Promise` and as long as the `await` is inside an `async` function, here's an example ( might not be the best, actually [it's a bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398699/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-a-constructor-function-return-a-promise) , but it's just to get this to work ):

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {      
      this.getData().then(({userId, title}) => {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.title = title;
        
        res(this);
      });
    });
  }
  
  getData(){
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())      
  }
  
  greet(){    
    console.log('hello');
  }
}


(async() => {
  const x = await new Test();
  console.log(x.userId, ' : ', x.title);
})();
```

Comment: This seems sketchy, even if it does work. `new Test()` should "be" a `Test`, not a `Promise`.

Comment: "should" be? this is javascript! anything can be anything

Comment: @crashmstr you can have the promise resolve with `this` : `res(this)` to have `Test` instead of `hello` , i can't think of a real usecase for this but .. *Technically, it's possible*

Comment: **use case**  Am writing some code that use knex _(knex uses promises to query the database)_ ... i want to re-use a class... i could re-use a function...a class seems more majestic and orderly. Great help @Taki.

Comment: @xaander1 OOP (not just javascript, check out asynchronous initializers using CompletionStage in Java) already has a design pattern for this - user the Builder pattern